# Word.Application permission denied error

Tags: vbscript, ms-office

I have Windows 10 installed and MS Word 2007 and IIS7. I have been using classic ASP and VBScript for coding.

I am using below code to print the doc file.

```
Dim oWord
Set oWord = Server.CreateObject("Word.Application")
oWord.Documents.Open "D:\Patient\PatientDocs\Template2.docx"
oWord.Activedocument.PrintOut
oWord.Quit
Set oWord = Nothing
```

and getting:

```
Server object error 'ASP 0178 : 80070005'

Server.CreateObject Access Error

/PATIENT/test.asp, line 21

The call to Server.CreateObject failed while checking permissions. Access is 
denied to this object.
```

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

> MS Word 2007 and IIS7. I have been using classic ASP and VBScript for coding.

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) article.

As a workaround you may consider using [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) if you deal with open XML documents only. Or just consider using any third-party components designed for the server-side execution.